# Get SymmetricKey from Swift binary

Tags: swift, security, reverse-engineering, lldb, frida

I'm trying to demonstrate that having a `CryptoKit.SymmetricKey` stored/generated in a binary isn't secure and made a test script:

```swift
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

let key = SymmetricKey(data: Data([0x18, 0xd3, 0x31, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x42, 0x55, 0x71, 0xb5, 0xaa, 0xa9, 0xcd, 0xd3, 0x1b, 0xb4, 0xd1, 0xac, 0xd9, 0x29, 0xd6, 0x18, 0x88, 0xbc, 0xee, 0x3f, 0xdf, 0x5e, 0x62, 0x2d, 0xa4, 0x6c, 0x10]))
let encryptedData = Data([0xa8, 0xf8, 0xf5, 0x79, 0x63, 0xb7, 0xb2, 0x7b, 0x00, 0xbe, 0x39, 0xf8, 0x2a, 0xb2, 0xeb, 0x4f, 0x6d, 0x77, 0x00, 0xe1, 0xd3, 0x7c, 0x15, 0x43, 0xa3, 0xb9, 0x50, 0xf1, 0x6d, 0x47, 0x3b, 0x79, 0xbc, 0x83, 0xee, 0xfe, 0x5e, 0xf1, 0xe5, 0x59, 0x85])

let sealedBox = try! ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: encryptedData)
let decryptedData = try! ChaChaPoly.open(sealedBox, using: key)
let decryptedString = String(decoding: decryptedData, as: UTF8.self)

print(decryptedString)
```

Which was generated from:

```swift
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

let message = "Hello, world!"

let nonce = ChaChaPoly.Nonce()
let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)

let keyData = key.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }
print("Key: \(keyData.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")

let sealedBox = try! ChaChaPoly.seal(message.data(using: .utf8)!, using: key, nonce: nonce)
print("Combined: \(sealedBox.combined.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")
```

I want to avoid just getting the array from the binary and instead get it from memory dumping/intercepting the CryptoKit calls to show that it's still possible if the key is obfuscated or from a different source. My goal is to at least get the key in hex and possibly the ciphertext or plaintext with it from practically any Swift binary with no debug symbols.

I've tried a few ideas:

## LLDB

I tried LLDB and setting breakpoints on the `CryptoKit.SymmetricKey.init<A where A: Foundation.ContiguousBytes>(data: A) -> CryptoKit.SymmetricKey` and `CryptoKit.ChaChaPoly.open(_: CryptoKit.ChaChaPoly.SealedBox, using: CryptoKit.SymmetricKey) throws -> Foundation.Data` calls but ran into some issues:

### Getting the memory address

I couldn't find how I could determine the memory address of the key. I tried compiling with debug symbols (`swiftc -g`) and used `frame var -L key` which gave me the address, but looking at the registers and disassembly, I wasn't sure how I could determine the address of the key without debug symbols.

### Getting the key data

Even with the address from using debug symbols, I couldn't find the key bytes. `expr -l Swift -- key.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()` worked, but casting to the struct myself didn't:

```
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- import CryptoKit
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- import Foundation
(lldb) frame var -L key
0x0000000100008028: (CryptoKit.SymmetricKey) key = {
0x0000000100008028:   sb = {
0x0000000100008028:     offset = 4296052176
  }
}
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- let $foo = unsafeBitCast(0x0000000100008028, to: SymmetricKey.self)
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- $foo.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

## Frida

I also tried writing a Frida script but I reached a dead end and wasn't sure where to go from here:

```js
{
  const getFunc = (name: string): "open" | "seal" => {
    if (name.includes("open_")) {
      return "open"
    } else if (name.includes("seal_")) {
      return "seal"
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unknown function")
    }
  }

  const module = Process.enumerateModules().find((module) => module.name === "CryptoKit")

  if (!module) {
    throw new Error("CryptoKit module not found")
  }

  for (const exp of module.enumerateExports()) {
    if (exp.name.includes("Symmetric") || exp.name.includes("Cha")) {
      Interceptor.attach(exp.address, {
        onEnter: (args) => {
          const func = getFunc(exp.name)
          switch (func) {
            case "open":
              // SealedBox, SymmetricKey
              console.log("Open called")
              break
            case "seal":
              console.log("Seal called")
              break
          }
        },
        onLeave: (retval) => {},
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Robert Ah I forgot to mention it, I did try it and it didn't seem to support this case yet. I don't have the script anymore and can't remember exactly what the issue was but I remember finding a comment from one of the devs saying it wasn't implemented yet after running into issues.

Comment: First thing I would do is loading the binary in IDA pro or Ghidra to first get the real function name of SymmetricKey constructor to hook and second check the `args` array for the key parameter. And second to see the real code that is executed with all the helper functions and wrappers Swift uses. The main problem then on the parameter is to understand in what format the key data parameter is stored in memory to get the raw data pointer so Frida can extract the memory.

Comment: @Robert I tried reading the memory of the key (using the address from `frame var -L key`) and couldn't find the bytes I passed in as the key. I also couldn't inspect the `SecureBytes` (`sb`) as easily since it's private but using the offset and looking at that area also didn't seem to make it obvious where the bytes were stored. Using LLDB at least feels like it should be easier since it can avoid the problem of figuring out the memory layout, but then I couldn't get the address.